# Calling c# function on string value BEFORE postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, razor

I am new to ASP, and have jumped right in and started a new MVC 4 project.
I am using the standard template and am trying to edit the login page. The problem I am trying to solve is this:
If you open Fiddler and login you can see the user name and password in plain text. What I would like to do would be to use a C# function I have created in a helpers file BEFORE the post is submitted, for example on a button click event, is this possible?
If so can someone point me in the direction of a tutorial/ example please as this has baffled me for a few days now!

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a C# function before the postback, how would you accomplish that? C# code runs server-side, but you post the form from the client-side. You can't apply a C# method on something you haven't shown it yet.

You have basically two options:

1.) use javascript to somehow alter the data before sending it to the server
2.) use SSL to protect the channel

The problem with the first option is, that ANYONE who sees the form can see your javascript code as well. In other words, no matter how strong protection you come up with, the attacker sees the algorithm, so he can decode the data very easily... Probably the most reliable option is the second one - SSL. It isn't 100%, but at least it's much harder to penetrate...

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use https instead so that data does not travel as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encrypt the data before the form is submitted you can only rely on client side code - javascript. This is in no way the optimal solution, as already pointed out by others, you should use https.